What does the "Rake::Task["db:reset"].invoke" command do?
I'm trying to find the script called by this Ruby/Rake command to find out exactly what is does ?
Rake::Task["db:reset"].invoke

I trying to find the script defining this command :
$ find /opt/gitlab/ -name "reset.rake" -o -name "reset.rb" 2>/dev/null
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/graphql/mutations/ci/runners_registration_token/reset.rb
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pry-0.14.2/lib/pry/commands/reset.rb
$

But none of them seem to be the script I'm looking for.
Can you please help me ?

so:

It's basically recreate your database
You can find it in rails source https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L164


The basic description is also contained in the Rails Documentation: Resetting the Database
